# Disable form find browser, if pressed Ctrl + F

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

How to disable form find browser, if pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and focus to element
**html**

```
<div id='demo'>
    <form class="id5-text-find-form" id="id5-text-find-form">
        <input class="search" placeholder="Find..." type="text">
        <input class="reset" type="reset" value="x">
    </form>
</div>


<textarea id="area">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.   
</textarea>
```

**css :**

```
#demo {
    display:none;
}
#area {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
kbd {
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding:4px;
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if ( e.ctrlKey && ( e.which === 70 ) ){
        $("#demo").show();
    }
})
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $("#demo").hide();
})
```

**Image :**

[image]

**[Fiddle Demo :](https://jsfiddle.net/ycgdd1gd/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `e.preventDefault()` within your keydown function to prevent default behavior

use `$(".search").focus();` to set focus

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if ( e.ctrlKey && ( e.which === 70 ) ){
        $("#demo").show();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".search").focus();
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ycgdd1gd/2/

Comment: Should probably .focus() the input as well.

Comment: can you confirm your os ? I'm on MAC and this doesn't work. maybe the ctrlkey ?

Comment: try using this on a mac `if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && ( e.which === 70 )`